# やれる 対 やる, whats the difference?

Tags: word-choice

What’s the difference between yareru and yaru? Dictionaries I have compared both say they are forms of “to do”, and they seem interchangeable to me.

Comment: https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-potential-form-conjugation/

Comment: This question seems terribly vague, what is the reason you think these are interchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

broccoli forest’s comment was what I was looking for! Thank you!

The website broccoli provided is super helpful, and is reposted below.

tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/verb-potential-form-conjugation